# MyBatis return hashmap real type

Tags: java, orm, mybatis

Here is the Dao code

```
@Select("select * from my_table order by id limit 1")
Map<String, String> selectFirst();
```

As you see, I specify the return type as `Map<String, String>`. And now comes the confusion:

```
Map<String, String> firstRow = myDao.selectFirst();
Object o = firstRow.get("id");
System.out.println(o.getClass()); // class java.lang.Integer
// java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
int id = Integer.parseInt(firstRow.get("id"));
```

So I get an `Integer` from a `Map<String, String>`, how could that happen?
If the real return type of the Dao method is `Map<String, Object>`, how could it be assigned to a `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: Generics is pure compile time concept. At runtime java uses something called as type erasure. So even though you have defined Map<String, String>, at runtime java sees it as a pure Map object. If you read in detail about how generics work, things will be more clear

Comment: @VishalKamat I do understand java generics have some limitations. But type erasure is not the excuse that MyBatis mistakenly allow me to return a `Map<String, String>` from the Dao method.

Answer (score 0):

Your DAO returns `untyped map`, which is the same as `Map<Object, Object>`. It is possible to assign it to typed map. But when you operate with collection elements, it will try to cast element to specified type and will throw an exception if cast is impossible.

```
        // untyped map
        Map objectMap = new HashMap();
        objectMap.put("key", new Integer(12));
        // assign
        Map<String, String> stringMap = objectMap;
        // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        System.out.print(stringMap.get("key"));
```

Solution: using `Map<Object, Object>` type or in this case `Map<String, Object>` will be ok.

```
        // untyped map
        Map objectMap = new HashMap();
        objectMap.put("key", new Integer(12));
        // assign
        Map<String, Object> stringMap = objectMap;
        System.out.print(stringMap.get("key"));
```

Comment: Do you have any proof that MyBatis return untyped map? Explanation with MyBatis source code is highly appreciated.